# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() while executing Network process

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, jakarta-mail

I am attempting to run a networking process in the background of my app, to send an email. Since it's a networking task, it has to be run on a separate thread in the background. However, I am unable to get the thread to execute properly. To start a new thread, I just create one, and run it using Thread.start(),

```
    new Thread(){


        public void run(){
                            Mail mail = new Mail();
            mail.setFrom("someone@example.com");
            mail.setTo("someone@to.com");
            mail.setSubject("Hello");
            mail.setMessage("World");

            try
            {
                if (mail.send())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Email Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Email Not Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("Debug","Could not send email - " + e);
                Log.i("Debug",e.getStackTrace().toString());
            }


        }
    }.start();
```

However, I always get the error 
     Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I tried a few other things, trying to pass `Looper.getMainLooper()` to the thread, via a Handler with Runnable, but it gives me the same error. I have also tried to use AsyncTask but it seems that since this is not a UI operation, use of AsyncTask is incorrect (plus, it also gives me the same error).

Here's my stacktrace

```
 03-01 16:14:43.305: I/GreenBook(4454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside     thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-01 16:14:43.305: I/GreenBook(4454):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
03-01 16:14:43.305: I/GreenBook(4454):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:361)
03-01 16:14:43.305: I/GreenBook(4454):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:97)
03-01 16:14:43.305: I/GreenBook(4454):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:254)
03-01 16:14:43.305: I/GreenBook(4454):  at     com.stacksmashers.greenbook.RegisterActivity$10.run(RegisterActivity.java:688)
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: It's in my question now.

Comment: You should provide your **full** stack trace.

Comment: This is the full stack trace. Only the thread caught an exception, so it did not crash the entire app, so the app kept running even after the thread crashed.

Comment: Which is the line 688 of your RegisterActivity.java file?

Comment: It is the line `if (mail.send())`, because it is waiting for the Mail send method to return after sending the mail. (I know the mail class/methods work, because I have tested them before)

Comment: Well, there's where the culprit is. This is probably creating a `Handler` and your `Thread` doesn't have the `Looper.prepare()` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

That is because you are trying to show a `Toast`.

> I have also tried to use AsyncTask but it seems that since this is not a UI operation, use of AsyncTask is incorrect

A `Toast` would be considered by most developers to be part of the UI.

> plus, it also gives me the same error

Perhaps you are trying to show the `Toast` from `doInBackground()`. Show your `Toast` in `onPostExecute()` (or `onProgressUpdate()`, if you elect to call `publishProgress()`).

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem! I didn't realize I was working with UI in my method. I just called the Toast in the OnProgressUpdate method, as part of the Async task.

Comment: check this library `compile 'com.shamanland:xdroid-toaster:0.0.5'`, it doesn't require `runOnUiThread()` or `Context` variable, all routine is gone! just invoke `Toaster.toast(R.string.my_msg);` here is the example: https://github.com/shamanland/xdroid-toaster-example